# Is there a way to DELETE a flag you submit?

Tags: feature-request, flag

Sometimes, I make a mistake and flag something, however, I have second thoughts and would really like to DELETE my flag.

Is there a mechanism to do this?  If not, wouldn't this be a good thing especially to the moderators who have to go through all the flags that we provide (in mistake somtime)?

I know you can see you flag in one of the places in the profile.  But you cannot DELETE them.  This would seem to be the perfect place to add this type of option.

We allow people to delete questions, and responses themselves how about flags? (again to save moderator time and aggravation by our mistakes)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-we-have-a-way-to-undo-a-flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way of clearing a flag, but I also wouldn't be too worried about it. 99.9% of the flags that come through are valid (even though I would say maybe 75% actually require moderator intervention), and we don't get that many flags anyway (compared to Stack Overflow)